# open fb messenger with welcome message from url in javascript

Tags: facebook-messenger

I want to open face book messenger application in mobile app from url. I have done this part using this url https://m.me/user_name. Here user_name is the fb user name. Now i want to add some dynamic welcome message when open application in mobile. How it can be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Facebook Developer Messenger-Platform system. Allows for automation and interaction responses with fairly rich graphical elements.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform

Comment: I did not find any solution from this link. i want to open facebook messenger app with dynamic message using javascript. We can open app for hit this link https://m.me. When we try to open this link in mobile browser the it will automatically redirect to face book messenger application. This process is fine. My next step which i want to achieve is thjat when my application is open i want to show dynamic message to user .

Comment: I do it using that set of APIs.

Comment: There are lots of open source projects that implement versions of this. Search around for facebook messenger chatbot on ie GitHub or wherever.

Comment: Do you have any link then plz share with me.

Comment: If you are unsure how to find an open source project you might be better off defining a Messenger Greeting text and using a link from JS like https://m.me/YourFacebookPageIdOrName . Here is the Facebook help page for setting your greeting text - good luck. https://www.facebook.com/help/1698046970464236